# how to run sencha app on a physical device

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I want to run my sencha app on an android tablet. I wrote "sencha app build" to compile it. And the compilation was successfull. But now how can I run it on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

1. Run command `sencha app build production`. It will create production build inside **build** folder.
2. You can use either cordova or phonegap,i am using cordova,you can install it by below command.

   *`npm install -g cordova`*
3. Create a cordova app in another directory.

   *`cordova create scraper com.test.scraper Scraper`*
4. Step 3 will create a directory scraper, Now execute below command in sequence's.

   *`cd scraper`*

   *`cordova platform add android`*
5. Now copy the build\production\scraper\ folder data(from step 1),Ex :-(your_app_name)\build\production\scraper\ to cordova app **www** folder.
6. Now run *`cordova app build android`*
7. Step 6 will create apk file inside `*platforms\android\ant-build\*` folder.Now you can install this apk to your android tablet.

For more Information,you can refer :-

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270566-Building-Sencha-Touch-2-Phonegap-Application-for-Android-Windows/page2

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface